# How to get the result of a calculation (increment) done in a method?

Tags: c#, methods, parameters, return-value, increment

I have been trying for more time than i would like to admit to get this to work. I'm pretty new at programming so this might be a very simple question. (I thought that when i started at least)

I really need to know how i can increase an existing value in increments using a method.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int TestValue = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(TestValue);
        TestingMethod(TestValue);
        Console.WriteLine(TestValue);
        TestingMethod(TestValue);
        Console.WriteLine(TestValue);
    }
    static int TestingMethod(int Start)
    {
        Start++;
        return Start;
    }
}
```

I want the program to print out 1, 2 and 3 using some sort of method. (preferably basic since i want to understand what i'm actually doing.) I also want to use multiple values with this method so simply putting in numbers won't work for me here.

I've already tried the things i know but since i don't have much knowledge of programming i may have used them incorrectly so they don't really matter i think.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is correct but you need to write:

```
Console.WriteLine(TestValue);
TestValue = TestingMethod(TestValue);
Console.WriteLine(TestValue);
TestValue = TestingMethod(TestValue);
Console.WriteLine(TestValue);
```

This works like using the string `Replace` method for example, where you need to assign to a string the result of the method, the same variable or another.

An alternative is to pass the parameter by [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref), so it will be modified, else it is [passed by value](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-value-type-and-reference-type) because int is a [value type](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int TestValue = 0;
    Console.WriteLine(TestValue);
    TestingMethod(ref TestValue);
    Console.WriteLine(TestValue);
    TestingMethod(ref TestValue);
    Console.WriteLine(TestValue);
}

static void TestingMethod(ref int Start)
{
    Start++;
}
```

[Passing Reference-Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-reference-type-parameters)

Comment: I Should've definitely asked here earlier. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Since “int Start” is not a reference, every time you call TestingMethod(TestValue) you are sending 0 to the method, you are also not doing anything to the return value, so the program always prints 0.

As the previous answer said, using ref at the signature is a good idea, another way of doing this could be by creating your own counter class that can be passed as a reference.

```
public class MethodCounter 
{
    private int counterValue = 0;
    
    public MethodCounter(int initialCount = 0)
    {
        counterValue = initialCount;
    }

    public void IncreaseCount()
    {
        counterValue++;
    }

    public int GetCount()
    {
        return counterValue;
    }
}
```

Making your program class look like this

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        MethodCounter counter = new MethodCounter();
        Console.WriteLine(counter.GetCount());
        TestingMethod(counter);
        Console.WriteLine(counter.GetCount());
        TestingMethod(counter);
        Console.WriteLine(counter.GetCount());
    }
    
    static void TestingMethod(MethodCounter counter)
    {
        counter.IncreaseCount();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When passing data into methods, there are two ways that it can happen

1. Pass-By-Reference
2. Pass-By-Value

Because `int` is a primivite data type, your data is being sent using pass-by-value by defualt. Here's a general reference for primitives https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type

When passing primitive type variables to methods, they are generally sent using Pass-By-Value. This means that the method receives a ***copy*** of your variable - and not the actual variable itself. Since the operations performed are being done on a different copy of your variable, your original copy isnt acutally being changed.

When passing Non-Primitive variables to a method (like `StringBuilder`, or `HttpClient`), they are generally sent using Pass-By-Reference. This means that you are passing the reference to your variable, aka the location in memory where it is stored. when the method receives the reference, it can find the exact copy of the variable you were working with, and perform operations on it

Answer (score -1):

As per your requirement, your code should look like this, you have not assigned the returned value to the `TestValue`.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        
        int TestValue = 0;
        TestValue = TestingMethod(TestValue);
        Console.WriteLine(TestValue);
        TestValue = TestingMethod(TestValue);
        Console.WriteLine(TestValue);
        TestValue = TestingMethod(TestValue);
        Console.WriteLine(TestValue);
    }
    
    static int TestingMethod(int Start)
    {
         return Start+=1;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your knowledge & experience. But your answer has a low quality. Sometimes a comment or a flag/close may be more relevant. To help you improve your answersplease read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), [How do I write a good answer to a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) & [Answering technical questions helpfully](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully).

Comment: Please do not post one hour later an identical answer of a previously posted answer.... It may be considered as flooding: by doing this often, you run the risk of having your account suspended.